# .json() only showing the first record from MariaDB table

Tags: node.js, next.js, mariadb

I am using the following code to fetch data from MariaDB database in json format in Next.js. I'm new to this, but from what I've learned, the code should show all the rows from the table. But the result in json format shows only the first row. The array format is also not showing. Any solution to fix this will be highly appreciated.

```js
const mariadb = require('mariadb');

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const dbconnection = await mariadb.createConnection({
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    database: "medipal",
    // port: 8889,
    user: "root",
    password: "password",
//socketPath: '\\\\.\\pipe\\MySQL'
  });
  try {
    const query = "SELECT hospital_id,name,image FROM hospital_l";
    const values = [];
    const [data] = await dbconnection.execute(query, values);
    dbconnection.end();

    res.status(200).json({ hospital_list: data });
  } catch (error) {
    // unhide to check error
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
}
```

The output:
[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vzh2Z.png)

The snippet of the database:
[the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUgCR.png)

Comment: Have you tried doing console.log the results before sending to response?

Comment: @Fawkes yes, I did. But only the first record shows up.

Comment: You query seems fine. I think there is some issue with `.execute()`, either in params or in response you're capturing. Can you try `.query()` instead and check results?